# How could I print a fibonacci sequence on different lines without using lists?

Tags: python, fibonacci

I am trying to calculate a simple fibonacci sequence and then print the numbers on different lines. However I want a specific amount of numbers on each line (ex: 5 numbers on each line).

```
a, b = 1, 1
while b < 150:
    print(b, "\n")
    a, b = b, a + b
```

The code above calculates a fibonacci sequence of numbers between 1 and 150 and is working just fine. I have tried using nested for/while loops and the \n keyword to print the sequence on different lines but I can't seem to get it to work. Could anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Hm. I don't really get your problem, could you specify what output you expect and what you get?

Comment: @MD98 So the program is calculating the fibonacci sequence properly. What I want is to print 5 numbers of the sequence on a line and then print another 5 on a new line and so on. My output currently is: "1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144". I would have used lists, but this is for my university coursework and we're not allowed to use lists or recursive functions. I have also tried using a for loop to tell the program to start a new line after 5 numbers have been printed but I didn't get it to work

Answer (score 1):

you could just count up and everytime you hit your max print the line break, like this:

```py
a, b, i = 1, 1, 0
while b < 150:
    print(f"{b}, ") # pretty print
    a, b = b, a + b
    i += 1
    if i > 5:
        print("\n")
        i = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would introduce a loop counter `i` so that you know when to print on the same line or not. `i % 5` can be used to make that decision. You could use the `end` parameter of `print` to specify this choice:

```
a, b = 1, 1
for i in range(15):
    print(b, end="\t\t\t\t\n"[i%5])
    a, b = b, a + b
```

So four times out of five this chooses the tab character as separator.